# how to download file from filesystem in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a filesystem in my app where files are been uploaded via paperclip and i dont know how to download the uploaded files that have been saved in the file system. if i do something like this `<%= link_to "Download", file.video.url %>` it brings out the download dialog in mozilla but plays the video in google crome. When i hosted the app it behaves in another dimention, i checked my log file and i c this

```
Started GET "/system/audios/3/original/03%20Breakdown.mp3?1317217561" for 41.206.12.58 at 2011-09-28 14:18:13 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/audios/3/original/03%20Breakdown.mp3"):
```

i dont know why this is hapenning.. is they a way i can do this by having a seprate download action.. if so i would like to know how. thank you(pls i am using paperclip for the upload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using [`send_file`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_file)? It allows you to specify that the file is an attachment. The `send_file` would be in your download action.

Comment: i have not tried using it before. Any brief sample would be good

Comment: i tried it out but i keep getting this error `Cannot read file /system/audios/1/original/03 Breakdown.mp3`

Comment: You'd likely need to give it an absolute path, but not sure.

Comment: thanks for the api i finally got it to work by doing this`  send_file @file.audio.path(:original),
            :type => @file.audio_content_type`

Comment: Ah, awesome--yeah, I should have suggested to use the whole Paperclip path thing; sorry.